# Undefined symbol using enum class

Tags: c++, enums, c++11, c++builder-xe2

This is probably a trivial question, but I am not able to overcome a problem with enum class data:

```
enum class enumTest
{
   VALUE0 = 0, VALUE1 = 1, VALUE2 = 2
};

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click (TObject* Sender)
{
int a = VALUE1;
}
```

I get: Error: Undefined symbol: 'VALUE1'

Changing enum class enum into:

```
enum //class enumTest
```

the compiler works normally.

Unfortunately I cannot do it because it is defined into the TLB/OCX include file, as many other declarations.
This happens with different types of OCX of different vendors.

Answer (score 14):

An `enum class` is called a *scoped enumeration*.  You need to use its enumerators in the scope of the enumeration.  For example,

```
int a = enumTest::VALUE1;
```

Comment: I thought `enum class` means you can't cast to int and vice versa, either. So `a` must be of type `enumTest` for this to compile.